# How to Graph Smooth Lines In Power BI Line Chart?

Tags: r, powerbi, linechart, linegraph

I have a request to make the lines in a line chart 'smoother'. The user would like to see a more 'polynomial look' in the graph.

I'm considering using R to do this, but is anyone aware of a way to do this without using R?

Much thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Line smoothing is not an option in the default visuals, some of the custom visuals may do it, I would start with looking at the [Spline chart](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380860?tab=Overview) (Free & requires R) or there is the [Zoom Charts](https://zoomcharts.com/en/microsoft-power-bi-custom-visuals/?variation=pbi-index-4) (Paid). I would recommend doing it in R, then formatting the visual to [match the look and feel](https://jlsql.blog/2019/02/19/theme-ggplot2-to-power-bis-visual-style/) of the Power BI visuals.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

With the recent Summer release this is now possible in the formatting pane for the line graph.

Visual Formatting Pane > Lines > Shape > Line Type

[image]